# UICollectionView Goes Wrong When Scroll Down

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm facing strange issue. My UICollectionView display half side colums if I scrolling to down. 
At first they show perfectly like this

[image]

But when I scrolling down, the UICollectionView behave strange and look like this :

[image]

Below is my code to populate data to layout (dummy) :

```
let layoutProduct: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layoutProduct.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
layoutProduct.scrollDirection = .vertical

collectionViewProduk = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layoutProduct)
collectionViewProduk.dataSource = self
collectionViewProduk.delegate = self
collectionViewProduk.register(ProdukPopulerCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ProductCell")
collectionViewProduk.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 231/255.0, green: 231/255.0, blue: 231/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
self.view.addSubview(collectionViewProduk)
```

How many data to show :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if collectionView == self.collectionViewByFilter {
            return 4
        } else if collectionView == self.collectionViewProduk {
            return 8
        }
        return section
}
```

How I populate dummy data to cell :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            if collectionView == self.collectionViewProduk {
                        if let cellA = collectionViewProduk.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ProductCell", for: indexPath) as? ProdukPopulerCell {
                            cellB.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

                            if indexPath.row < 8  {
                                cellB.nameLabel.text = "Product"
                                cellB.theImageView.image = UIImage(named: "biometric")
                                cellB.priceLabel.text = "Rp 30.000"
                            }
                            return cellB
                        }
            }
            return UICollectionViewCell()
}
```

How I layouting the cell and make them look 2 cell in 1 rows :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        if collectionView == self.collectionViewProduk {
            let collectionViewSize = collectionViewProduk.frame.size.width - 10
            return CGSize(width: collectionViewSize / 2, height: collectionViewSize / 2)
        }
        return CGSize()
}
```

Can you guys spot the mistake that I make?

Comment: check scroll direction and set it accordingly u require.

Comment: I guess you are miscalculating the height and widht for the cell. consider distance between the cells.

Comment: @ravi.p I already set it "layoutProduct.scrollDirection = .vertical"

Comment: Check the size of the cell before and after the issue, may be it will help you solve the problem..?

Answer (score 0):

Create a customCollectionViewFlowLayout and apply it to your collectionview

```
    import UIKit

    class customCollectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        override init() {
            super.init()
            setupLayout()
        }

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: aDecoder)
            setupLayout()
        }

        func setupLayout() {
            minimumInteritemSpacing = 1
            minimumLineSpacing = 1
            scrollDirection = .vertical
        }

        override var itemSize: CGSize {
            set {

            }
            get {
                let numberOfColumns: CGFloat = 2

                let itemWidth = (self.collectionView!.frame.width - (numberOfColumns - 1)) / numberOfColumns
                return CGSize(width:itemWidth, height:itemWidth)
            }
        }
    }
```

then apply it to your collectionview

```
  yourCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = customCollectionViewFlowLayout()
```